# Connectivity in a molecule and permutations

Tags: graphs-and-networks, permutation, chemistry

What am I trying to do is to make a script that calculates all chemically reasonable torsion angles in any molecule.

For one torsional angle I need 4 CONNECTED atoms, 1-2-3-4, 1-2-3 defining one plane, and 2-3-4 defining the other.

I was thinking of doing something of a form: 
"IF (distance between 1 and 2 is between 0,9 and 1,4 Angstroms), 
AND (distance between 2 and 3 is between 1 and 1,4 Angstroms), 
AND (distance between 3 and 4 is between 0,9 and 1,4 Angstroms), 
calculate torsion angle between planes defined by atoms 1-2-3 and 2-3-4".

Since I just got my hands on Mathematica, I have no idea how to do that.

Main problem is how to write a loop which would go through all permutations of 4 atoms in set of, for example, 10 atoms.

Stucture is given in XYZ format.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You can read [`Permutations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html) to generate the permutations and `Map` to avoid writing explicitely a loop.

Comment: It will be useful for you to go through a few basic tutorials first: https://www.wolfram.com/language/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Getting the graph from the XYZ file

You have only a set of coordinates and atom types in an XYZ file. When you import it in *Mathematica* you can import 3 elements: the 3D plot, the coordinates, and atom types

```
{plot, coords, atoms} = 
  Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nutjunkie/IQmol/master/share/fragments/Molecules/Amino_Acids/L-Cysteine.xyz"
, {"XYZ", {"Graphics3D", "VertexCoordinates", "VertexTypes"}}];
```

This is our small molecule, cysteine,

[image]

To work with the chemical graph, you also need the bonds.  Here is an easy way we can get them manually; first we grab every single pair of atoms, using [`Subsets`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subsets.html), and then use Select along with EuclideanDistance to choose only the bonds in a certain size range.  Notice that the coordinates are in picometers even though the XYZ file is written in angstroms.

```
vertexlist = Range@Length@atoms;
bonds = Select[Subsets[vertexlist, {2}], 
  90 < EuclideanDistance @@ coords[[#]] < 140 &]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {6, 7}, {6, 13}, {8, 9}, {8, 
  10}, {10, 11}, {12, 14}} *)
```

Let's look at the molecule as a `Graph3D`,

```
Graph3D[vertexlist, UndirectedEdge @@@ bonds, 
 VertexCoordinates -> coords/100]
```

[image]

You can see we didn't catch all the bonds that the `Import` function did (1.4 angstroms is shorter than many carbon-carbon or carbon-sulfur bonds).  So let's use the same undocumented function that it used to infer the bonds,

```
bonds = UndirectedEdge @@@
 Graphics`MoleculePlotDump`InferBonds[atoms, coords, 40, 25]
```

[image]

Now we have a connected molecule

```
chemicalGraph = 
 Graph3D[vertexlist, UndirectedEdge @@@ bonds, 
  VertexCoordinates -> coords/200]
```

[image]

## Getting all dihedral angles

Here's a [brute force method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84743/9490) to find all the sets of 4 atoms that make a connected subgraph,

```
subgraphs = 
  Select[Subgraph[chemicalGraph, #] & /@ Subsets[vertexlist, {4}], 
   ConnectedGraphQ];
```

Now we just need the dihedral angle for each fragment.  We can use the method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/47084/210969) to get the dihedral angle from the three vectors.  Here are some helper functions,

```
vectorFromEdge[edge_] := coords[[First@edge]] - coords[[Last@edge]];
vectorsFromSubgraph[sg_] := vectorFromEdge /@ EdgeList[sg];
dihedralFromVectors[{b1_, b2_, b3_}] := Module[{n1, n2},
  n1 = Normalize@Cross[b1, b2];
  n2 = Normalize@Cross[b2, b3];
  ArcTan[n1.n2, Cross[n1, Normalize@b2].n2]
  ];
dihedralsFromSubgraph[sg_] := dihedralFromVectors /@ 
                  Permutations[vectorsFromSubgraph[sg]];
```

Now that we have the tools to get the angle, let's visualize one set of points and the planes that make the dihedral angle,

```
plot2 = plot /. {Sphere[a__] :> Sequence[], 
    Cylinder[a__] :> Tube[a]};
Show[
 plot2,
 With[{points = coords[[ VertexList[subgraphs[[2]]]]]},
  Graphics3D[
   {Red, Sphere[#, 40] & /@ points,
    Green, 
    InfinitePlane[points[[1]], 
     Most@vectorsFromSubgraph@subgraphs[[2]]],
    Blue, 
    InfinitePlane[points[[-1]], 
     Rest@vectorsFromSubgraph@subgraphs[[2]]]}
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

and the dihedral ange shown is

```
dihedralFromVectors @vectorsFromSubgraph@subgraphs[[2]]
%/Degree
(* 0.973156 *)
(* 55.7577 *)
```

You can get all the dihedral angels from the subgraph,

```
dihedralsFromSubgraph@subgraphs[[2]]
(* {0.973156, -2.08642, -2.1166, 2.08642, 2.1166, -0.973156} *)
```

3 unique dihedrals, and then repeated but negative.

You can get all the dihedral angles and do a histogram

```
dihedralsFromSubgraph /@ subgraphs // Flatten // Histogram
```

[image]

If you wanted to do the same thing using a molecule from the Wolfram Knowledgebase, you can just use `EntityValue` to grab the graph components. Here is the distribution of dihedral angles in buckminsterfullerene

```
{plot, coords, atoms, bonds} = EntityValue[
   Entity["Chemical", "FullereneC60"], {"MoleculePlot", 
    "AtomPositions", "VertexTypes", "EdgeRules"}
   ];
vertexlist = Range@Length@atoms;
chemicalGraph = 
 Graph3D[vertexlist, UndirectedEdge @@@ bonds, 
  VertexCoordinates -> coords/200]
subgraphs = 
  Select[Subgraph[chemicalGraph, #] & /@ Subsets[vertexlist, {4}], 
   ConnectedGraphQ];
```

Finding the subgraphs took a bit more time in this case.  You could probably find a better way to search for them.

I made an interactive tool for querying bond angles, lengths, and dihedral angles in molecules. It is posted [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/963198) on the community site

[image]
[image]